# i want to apply Night mode to all my activities

Tags: java, android

I want to apply Night mode to all my activities.

I have recently added a night mode feature to my app and it works fine. But the think is that as soon as I exit that activity it gets disabled. So I want to apply this feature to all my activities as soon as I switch between night mode and day mode.

[image]

How can I apply this mode to every activity when it is changed to day or night. I also want to change the notification bar to black and to normal.

Answer (score 2):

you can use base activity. And extends your main activity with this base activity. perform the specific task in base activity.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that as i am never been through this thing

Comment: Make a base activity in which u can do all the thing u want to do with night mode and in your main activity just extends this base activity in main activity. So u can use all the thing of base activity in the main activity.

Comment: I did that for my base activity like this - *public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity*
but i get an error when i extend it to other activity coz i have this line-
*public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity*

so how can i extend it now?

Comment: how can i extend it in this line

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Extends BaseActivity in MainActivity instead of AppCompatActivity.